# Error triying get static ip working like dhcp show

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vmware

I have the following situation:

> Sorry for img but i dont have any way to copy text from console in VM running.

1. I have configured a virtual machine with VMware, the host is Windows 10 and the guest is Ubuntu Server 20.04.
2. I have shared my wired local network with the VMnet8 by default which is "NAT" and it has been left side of windows 10 like this:

[image]

3. in VMware I have been left with the configuration with the following data:

[image]

4. the virtual machine has the network configured as follows:

[image]

once I have already verified that if I have Internet connectivity and I install all the pending updates of the server's S.O. and I have installed SHH to connect remotely; I look for all the necessary data of the DHCP configuration to pass it to a static version:

A. excecute: `ip a` command to view the `ip` in `dhcp` mode and i get this:

[image]

B. excecute: `ip route` and `show` this:

[image]

I have configured the `00-installer-config.yaml` to convert the dhcp information to a correct static configuration like this:

[image]

**but this not work i dont know what i am missing.**

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Gateway should be `192.168.1.2` same as DNS